# Deploying Node + MongoDB API on AWS or GCP

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, api, google-cloud-platform

I am working on a Node + MongoDB API and the API is deployed on a VM on Google Cloud Platform. Currently, the data is stored in a MongoDB instance running on the VM.

Is running a local MongoDB instance for production a good practice? And how does various cloud services providing MongoDB compare with each other? And what are some good practices to ensure the API is scalable? Also can deploying API to Kubernetes as a container offer better results as compared to VMs?

Comment: One possible thought is to use one of Google's own databases for data storage.  These databases such as Google Datastore - https://cloud.google.com/datastore/ - provide a managed databases as a service.  There is nothing for you to manage and scaling is just built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having both server and database running in the same VM instance would always be a bad idea for a service that you want to scale. Let's think what happen if your instance could not handle the number of traffic being sent into anymore?

At first you might just do the vertical scale adding more CPU and RAM to the currently running instance and yes, that would be fine for some period of time. But it is actually more like a temporary life-extending plan since at some point, your instance will not be able to do the vertical scale anymore. And here come the horizontal scale...

New instance has to be created to handle the increasing number of traffic and how would you design the new instance for that?

The best practice is to have an instance that looks exactly the same as the first one. So the server is needed to be designed as a **stateless** one. In this case, your instance will be able to scale for at any number of machine.

That's why you should not have the API front end and database running in the same instance. It could not be scaled.

So how's about the database? It is quite straightforward. Just simply place it in the another VM instance! If database is still be able to handle the request, you can just share the database server among the server instances. But if there is a bottleneck on the database side, you can scale your mongoDB separately with cluster or so.

If you don't have time, you can consider using the ready-to-use service like Heroku Add-On, for example, [mongolab](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab), to managing the MongoDB instance for you.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the response